# DSL Tools: Centralizar um shape no diagrama

Tags: c#, visual-studio, modelagem, sdk

Estou desenvolvendo uma DSL. Na janela principal, tenho dois painéis (*Panel*): em um, uma lista (*listbox*) dos *shapes* do diagrama, e no outro, o diagrama em si. Gostaria, **ao clicar em um item na lista, para centralizar o *shape* correspondente na tela** (painel do diagrama).

**Não quero mover o *shape* para o centro do diagrama mudando suas coordenadas x,y. Quero rolar o diagrama para centralizar o *shape***

Outra maneira de explicar: quando ocorre um erro de validação (janela de Erros na parte inferior), e ao clicar no erro, ele centraliza o *shape* inválido na tela, certo? Isso é o que eu quero.

**Ponto de partida:**

```
private void symbolsListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var listBox = sender as ListBox;
    var symbol = listBox.SelectedItem as Symbol;
    var compartment = PresentationViewsSubject.GetPresentation(symbol)
        .FirstOrDefault() as SymbolCompartmentShape;
    var diagram = docView.CurrentDiagram;

    //Next step, center the shape
    //How? God please help me!!!
}
```

**O exemplo com imagem é sempre melhor!! então...**

[image: AQUI, UMA IMAGEM DE EXEMPLO DO QUE EU QUERO]
[image: AQUI, UM EXEMPLO DE IMAGEM DO RESULTADO ESPERADO]

Dica do amigo Francisco nos comentários: **Tradução dos textos da imagem**
**Imagem 1: "Quero clicar aqui... então centralizar isso"

Imagem 2: "Item clicado; shape centralizado. Note que o scroll quem se moveu, não o shape"**

Comment: Este é um site em Português e nem todo mundo aqui sabe inglês, caso o texto da imagem seja relevante para a pergunta, por favor deixe a tradução.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, é pq eu fiz a pergunta primeiro no site em inglês e aproveitei a imagem. Mas acho que dá pra entender. Quem programa no VS e tem conhecimento pra responder vai saber o que está escrito. Mas valeu a dica, não tinha pensado nisso. :)